# Xcode 9.2: No "New Framework" in "File-> New" menu

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, frameworks, swift-framework

Xcode 9.2: No "New Framework" in "File-> New" menu

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new project
2. Go to File->New
3. No "Framework" item is visible.

Is it a bug, or has Apple changed the way to create frameworks in Xcode v 9.2?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frameworks are under New Project ...

File -> New -> Project

[image]

Comment: Thanks! "It's that easy"